# ecg cable is there any different from brand to another

Tags: electrical-engineering, medical-devices

i have this device but ecg  3 lead cable is missing
my question can i use different brand ecg cable  for this device [image]
[image: ecg heat monitor device]

[image]

the second picture plug I have

the last picture is missing can i use different one from another brand

Comment: probably not, unless there is a standard that covers the characteristics of the cable

Comment: @jsotola Are you answering the question in the title or the question in the body?

Comment: the comment refers to `my question can i use different brand ecg cable for this device` ... the OP had not used any question marks, so that is the only one that is specifically identified as a question that seeks an answer